# How to cmake AWSSDK properly?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, cmake

I want to use AWS sdk for my c++ project.
I am using cmake command like this:

```
find_package(AWSSDK REQUIRED COMPONENTS sqs)
```

I have an error

```
CMake Error at MyDirr/CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindAWSSDK.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "AWSSDK", but
  CMake did not find one.
```

I did

```
 brew install awscli  
 which aws                # prints: /opt/homebrew/bin/aws
```

How to install AWSSDK into my c++ project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the AWS SDK for C++, first build the SDK from source and then install it locally. This process differs depending if you are building on Windows or MAC/Linux.

These instructions are documented in the AWS DEV Guide for C++. Look at this topic:

[Get the AWS SDK for C++ from source code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/sdk-from-source.html)

Follow these instructions to install AWS SDK for C++ into your project.